# httpd forbidding access to files not created in /var/www/html/

Tags: html, linux, apache, webserver

I'm playing around with a webserver and have encountered a peculiar problem. I have a brand new Centos7 httpd (Apache) webserver.

If run this sequence:

```
sudo vi /var/www/html/ first.html
# enter "<p>hello</p>" and save
```

And hit `{IP Address}/first.html` it works as expected and displays "hello" in the browser.
But when I do this:

```
sudo vi /home/centos/second.html
# enter "<p>hello</p>" and save
sudo mv /home/centos/second.html /var/www/html/second.html
```

And hit `{IP Address}/second.html` it returns a 403 `Forbidden You don't have permission to access/second.html on this server.`

I performed `ls -al` with this as the output:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 13 Aug 18 23:33 first.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 13 Aug 18 23:34 second.html
```

And I performed a hex dump to confirm every bit was the same for the following output:

```
[centos@ip-172-31-10-192 html]$ hexdump -C first.html 
00000000  3c 70 3e 68 65 6c 6c 6f  3c 2f 70 3e 0a           |<p>hello</p>.|
0000000d
[centos@ip-172-31-10-192 html]$ hexdump -C second.html 
00000000  3c 70 3e 68 65 6c 6c 6f  3c 2f 70 3e 0a           |<p>hello</p>.|
0000000d
```

As you can see, there are no differences in the files themselves. Now, I assumed that somehow the creation process edits some configuration file enabling access to `first.html` but not `second.html` so I ran `grep -rin "first"  /etc/httpd/` and `grep -rin "second" /etc/httpd/` and found no relevant output. So what the heck is going on? Why is an html file that is created via `vi` then `mv` treated differently than an identical file created directly via `vi`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution as well as what the problem was before I pressed send on this question but wanted to pass this along for anyone else.

*The problem stemmed from the fact that I used `mv` to move an existing file to a webserver instead of `cp` which would have created a new file.*

Credit goes to TrevorH over at https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=6834.

> The issue is caused when you mv something from one place to another. It preserves the selinux context of the original when you move it, so if you untar something in /home or /tmp it gets given an selinux context that matches its location. Now you mv that to /var/www/html and it takes the context saying it belongs in /tmp or /home with it and httpd is not allowed by policy to access those files.

> If you cp the files instead of mv them, the selinux context gets assigned according to the location you're copying to, not where it's coming from. Running restorecon puts the context back to its default and fixes it too.

Comment: To solve this issue, simply run `restorecon -r /var/www/html`.